# How to hide the black space created during carousel image resizing?

Tags: css, image, resize

In [my website](http://www.electronicsmentor.com), i have placed an image after the navigation bar. What i expect is the image re-size itself according to the size of the screen. Actually it does re-size but it leaves a blank space above the image when it re sizes which looks award.

The image fits exactly when the scrren resolution is above 1170px. But when i re-size it to lower resolutions it tends to introduce the blank space.

I have tried many element styles like margin-top: auto, margin-bottom:auto etc. But i couldn't hide that space dynamically. I am so new to the web site development. please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Actually I cant see any blank space dude.

Comment: Is it internet explorer you're testing on? of course :)

Answer (score 0):

change the style:

```
.carousel_gallery_item_inner { vertical-align:bottom;}
```

to:

```
.carousel_gallery_item_inner { vertical:align:top;}
```